# Issue saving changes made in excel by python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have a Python program which needs to do the following thing: Open an excel file, save it as a new copy, then in the new copy write something, then save. The program runs. According to the console output, the word gets added to the cell, but when I open it, it is nowhere to be seen.

I know that Microsoft doesn't officially support automating Office, but this needs to be done.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import tkinter as tk
import os
import openpyxl
from tkinter import messagebox
from openpyxl import load_workbook  
from datetime import datetime
from pywintypes import com_error
import time
import logging
import itertools

starter_row = 7

def get_time():
    now=datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
    return current_time    


try:
    excel=win32.gencache.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
except:
    excel=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
old_file_path = excel.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter="Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xlsm), *.xlsx; *.xlsm")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(old_file_path)
wb.RefreshAll()  ## Refresh external connection datas
excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()  ## Wait until the refresh has completed
file_name = os.path.basename(old_file_path)
directory_path = os.path.dirname(old_file_path).replace('\\', "/")
#We make a copy of the file with the current date and time, then open that one, so the original stays intact.
new_file_name = (file_name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]) + '_' + get_time() + '.xlsm'
file_path = directory_path + '/' + new_file_name
wb.SaveCopyAs (file_path)
excel.Quit()
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
ws = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path).active
sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path).Sheets('Messstellenplanung')

print("active worksheet: ", ws, " filepath: ", file_path)
print(ws['Q3'].value)
cell= ws['Q3']
cell.value = cell.value + "Testing123"
print(ws['Q3'].value)

for wb in excel.Workbooks:
    print("WB:",wb.Name)
    wb.Save()
wb.RefreshAll()
messagebox.showinfo(title="Success",message=f"The program ran succesfully. The new file's name is: {new_file_name}")
```

Comment: Is this line relevant? `sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path).Sheets('Messstellenplanung')`
Are you expecting the result in any active sheet, ot in this `Messstellenplanung` one?

Comment: @defaultUsernameN I expect the result in that sheet specifically, as I'm working with a template I was given.

Comment: But the variable you get for the `Messstellenplanung` (the `sheet` variable) is not the one you make the edit to, is that maybe your issue？You shoud be using `sheet` instead of `ws` I think

Comment: I don't think so, as the two 'print(ws['Q3'].value)' calls give me the correct before and after results I'm expecting. It just doesn't get saved for some reason.

Comment: Just to make sure: does searching for "Testing123" through the whole new doc yield no results? I think it's something like "select all worksheets => use find and replace" in excel

Comment: I searched it, sadly nowhere in the workbook does it give a result. Also, out of curiosity I replaced 'ws' with 'sheet' and i got the following error: 'TypeError: '_Worksheet' object is not subscriptable' so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: for more context,I'd like to show the output of the two "print(ws['Q3'].value)" calls (3 rows, the third row is empty but present): NDA_fillertext
NDA_fillertext

;
NDA_fillertext
NDA_fillertext
Testing123

Comment: Might be another fluke but another thing I see is that the .`Save()` is called on all excel.Workbooks() instead of on the specific one that you definitely edited, an I am not sure the one you edited is in this array.

Comment: Try maybe having explicit reference to it: `wb = load_workbook(file_path); ws = wb.active; `, then your editing in cells, and then `wb.Save()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are using `win32com` and `openpyxl` together, which is not recommended. Try using one library.

```py
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
ws = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path).active
sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path).Sheets('Messstellenplanung')
```

In the above code, you are opening the file using `win32com` in the first line. Then opening the same file using `openpyxl` Instead of the above use the below code

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
ws = wb['Messstellenplanung']
```

Instead of using for loop, which is unnecessary, directly save and close the file after making the changes.

```py
cell = ws['Q3']
cell.value = cell.value + 'Testing123'
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I removed the openpyxl lines as there were fewer of those. Rewriting it to win32com solved my problem instantly, thanks!